# conditioning by independent sigma-algebras

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $X$ a random variable, $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$, two $\sigma$-algebras such that $\sigma(X,\mathcal{A})$ is independent of $\mathcal{B}$.

Is it always true that $\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B})]=\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{A}]$?

I can show it for $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ finite algebras, but I do not know how to extend it to general sigma-algebras.

Comment: How do you do it for algebras?

Answer (score 1):

What we have to show is that the equation
$$\int_CX\mathrm d\mu=\int_C\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal A]\mathrm d\mu$$
holds true for any $C\in\sigma(\mathcal A,\mathcal B)$. One can see that by the assumption of independence, it's true when $C=A\cap B$ for some $A\in\mathcal A$ and $B\in\mathcal B
$. The class $\mathcal C=\{A\cap B,A\in\mathcal A,B\in\mathcal B\}$ is stable by finite intersections, and we can conclude by [Dynkin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Dynkin.27s_.CF.80-.CE.BB_Theorem).

Comment: how would be the first step of the proof? I thought at: $\int_A XdP \int_BXdP = \int_A E[X|\mathscr A]  \int_B E[X|\mathscr A]$. and then? What happen when I integrate for some B$\in \mathscr B$ an $\mathscr A$ measurable r.v.?